# Pegar caminho de arquivo após upload?

Tags: javascript, email, upload, vue.js, anexo

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de emails usando VueJS  e estou na parte de anexos, e quero pegar o caminho do arquivo pois só ele basta para que eu possa enviar o anexo usando o nodemailer.

Tem algum método que eu possa pegar o caminho do arquivo que eu escolhi para upload como anexo depois de ser efetuado o upload dele para o servidor??

Comment: Isso você pega no node, não no front-end. A pergunta está muito ampla, melhor você dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Então, primeiro você tem que realizar o upload do arquivo, após sua aplicação enviar o upload, ela deve retornar o caminho do arquivo e somente neste ponto, prosseguir com a programação.

Comment: Entendi @BrunoRigolon,  e você sabe onde quais os métodos para pegar o caminho do arquivo depois de fazer o upload??

Comment: @bfavaretto, vou editar a pegunta para especificar mais ela...

Comment: @bfavaretto, mudei um pouco, se quiser editar também, sinta-se à vontade...

Comment: Pra pegar o caminho do arquivo, você precisa entrar isso no backend. No PHP você tem este dado em $_FILES, em node, req.files.upload.path, onde req é o a variável que você denomina a requisição. Após processar no backend, você devolve apenas o caminho do arquivo em sua chamada ajax. Na chamada ajax você receberá o caminho do arquivo e prossegue com a programação. Dê uma analisada neste link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-handle-file-uploads-in-vue-2. Com ele você tem uma boa base para fazer o que precisa.

Comment: Entendi a lógica, no caso eu teria que fazer o upload primeiro, colocar em um diretório no servidor, aí pegar o path do arquivo e aí anexar no email, agora entendi como fazer, os métodos para isso ainda vou descobrir, mas é possível com uma ajuda do fs do node, acrescente como resposta o eu comentário para mim aceitar ele...

Comment: Agora que você explicou entendi bem e vi que já estava quase tudo pronto no meu servidor, só falta atribuir a variável com o caminho no `attachments[]` do nodemailer